# Python class inheritance - how to use this to connect to a mysql database

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, class, inheritance

I am using python 2.7 and I have written a set of python classes in order to upload data to my database. However I am not sure I am completely understanding  how to use inheritance from class to class. What I have is a User and Database class - which searches for the users/ databases from a list:

```
class User(object):

    user_lst = ['user1', 'user2', 'user3']

    def __init__(self, username):
        self.username = username

    def find_user(self):
        if self.username not in self.user_lst:
            print('User not found, script will exit')
            exit()
        else:
            pass


class Database(object):

    db_lst = ['db1', 'db2', 'db3']

    def __init__(self, database):
        self.database = database

    def find_db(self):
        if self.database not in self.user_lst:
            print('Database not found, script will exit')
            exit()
        else:
            pass
```

I get my values for user and database using raw_input() which returns:

```
un = 'user1'
db = 'db1'
```

To instantiate these classes as I understand it, I need to pass these values through the class, at which time I can also call the methods -

```
User(un).find_user()
Database(db).find_db()
```

I now want to use a third class to inherit these values in order to connect to the database:

```
class DatabaseConnect(User, Database):

    def __init__(self):
        User.__init__(self, username)
        Database.__init__(self, database)

    def connect(self, pw):
        try:
            connect = MySQLdb.connect(host = 'localhost', user = self.username, passwd = pw, db = self.database, local_infile = 1)
            cursor = connect.cursor()
            print('Connected to '+self.database)
        except:
            print('Did not connect to database')
            exit()
```

I then try and connect using:

```
DatabaseConnect().connect('password1')
```

However this doesn't work. I have tried to add to my DatabaseConnect class **init** function:

```
def __init__(self, username, database):
    User.__init__(self, username)
    Database.__init__(self, database)
```

I have also played around with creating object variables from these classes such as:

```
user_obj = User(un)
user_obj.find_user()

db_obj = Database(db)
db_obj.find_user()
```

Do I need to create these object variables and then pass them through my DatabaseConnection class - if so do I even need to inherit? This is why I am confused. Say I use these object variables and use this class:

```
class DatabaseConnect(User, Database):

    def __init__(self, username, database):
        self.username = User.username
        self.database = Database.database

    def connect(self, pw):
        try:
            connect = MySQLdb.connect(host = 'localhost', user = self.username, passwd = pw, db = self.database, local_infile = 1)
            cursor = connect.cursor()
            print('Connected to '+self.database)
        except:
            print('Did not connect to database')
            exit()
```

and then I instantiate it using:

```
db_connect = DatabaseConnect(user_obj, db_obj)
```

How is this any different from simply using the variables themselves:

```
db_connect = DatabaseConnect(un, db)
```

and why do i have to use:

```
self.username = User.username
```

instead of simply:

```
self.username = username
```

I am struggling to get my head around this concept so any head would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are inheriting you dont need to create a User and Database instance. You can just create a DatabaseConnect object:

```
class DatabaseConnect(User, Database):

    def __init__(self, username, database):
        User.__init__(self, username)
        Database.__init__(self, database)

    def connect(self, pw):
        try:
            connect = MySQLdb.connect(host = 'localhost', user = self.username, passwd = pw, db = self.database, local_infile = 1)
            cursor = connect.cursor()
            print('Connected to '+self.database)
        except:
            print('Did not connect to database')
            exit()


dbConnect = new DatabaseConnect("username", "database")

dbConnect.find_db()
Database not found, script will exit

dbConnect.find_user()
User not found, script will exit
```

Comment: Ah, 14 seconds earlier

Comment: Thank you. But I'm still confused. I dont get what the point of doing this is - because without instantiating my User and Database classes I can't call the find_user() and find_database methods, right?

Also, how is this any different from simply putting in my DatabaseConnect:

def __init__(self, username, database):
'self.username = username 
 self.database = database

This would have the same result?

Comment: Yes you can, you now can do this  dbConnect.find_db() and dbConnect.find_user() I update my answer

Comment: When you instantiate DatabaseConnect and called User and Database init you have access to these methods and properties also

Comment: I understand now! Thank you very much! So basically when you call the child class which inherits from parent classes you can now access their methods - great :D

Comment: Yes, the only tricky methods are the default class methods like __init__ which are called the same and you have to use User.__init__ syntax, but custom methods like dbConnect.find_user() are easily accesed

Comment: When the child and parent method is called the same you have to specify which one to use with User.method or Database.method etc

Comment: so if both of these methods were called 'find', and i tried to call it using: dbConnect.find() - it would not know which one to use. So would I call it using dbConnect.User.Find()?

Comment: That wouldnt work well, you probably would need to tweak User and Database classes to inherint one from each other, something like this https://www.quora.com/In-multiple-inheritance-if-all-parents-have-the-same-method-the-same-method-name-how-does-the-child-call-every-method-in-its-parents-class

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122386/discussion-between-trouselife-and-lapinkoira).

Answer (score 0):

By doing:

```
def __init__(self, username, database):
    self.username = User.username
    self.database = Database.database
```

you are not properly initialising the `User` and `Database` instances. You need to call their `__init__` function. There are several ways to do so e.g.:

```
def __init__(self, username, database):
    User.__init__(self, username)
    Database.__init__(self, database)
```

after doing so you can use `self.username`, etc